# Incompatible types in assignment in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, structure

I'm having a bit of issue with pointers and structures in c.

```
struct foo{
char a[15];
}

void asn_foo(struct foo *pa){
    (*pa).a = "123";
}

main()
{
    struct foo foo1[2], *pf;
    pf = &(foo1[0]);
    asn_foo(pf);
}
```

I'm trying to assign a new value by:

```
(*pa).a = "123";
```

but I have the error "Incompatible types in assignment" on this line.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Voting to close, this is a FAQ: http://c-faq.com/charstring/assign.html

Comment: It's an OK question for SO unless you can point to the duplicate on SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Char array in a struct - incompatible assignment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292586/char-array-in-a-struct-incompatible-assignment)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't assign new values to an array using the assignment operator, you have to copy the contents of the string `"123"` into your array. Use `strcpy` to do so:

```
strcpy(pa->a, "123");
```

Another trick is also wrapping your array in a `struct` (as you've done here), and assigning one struct to another in order to assign new values to your array.

You *can* do:

```
struct foo f1 = { "abc" };
struct foo f2 = { "123" };
f1 = f2;
```

`f1.a` will now hold `"123"`.

Also, `main` should return an `int`.