# How do I use an array variable inside an array of structures?

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I'm trying to grasp the concept of arrays of structures and came up with a problem. Hopefully you can help me out.

Okay, so, the problem I'm facing is how to declare and use (i.e. accept & display values) of an array variable within an array of structures?

This sample code may visually help you to understand my problem:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct node{

    int roll;
    char name[10];
    int grades[5]; // Accepts 5 grades for each student
};

int main()
{
    struct node student[3];

    /*Accept and display values for structure members here*/

    return 0;
}
```

I know there's a similar example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827205/accessing-the-array-inside-array-of-structures).

But I don't understand *line 4* in the accepted answer's `main()` section, where memory is allocated using `malloc()` :

`list[ip].inputs[inp]= (char*)malloc(25);`

I'm getting confused between the 25 bytes allocated here and the 10 defined in `char* inputs[10];`

What exactly is happening here? And how do you solve the problem I mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an extra `*` in the example you quote. The `malloc` is needed only because of that, in your example `inputs` is an array of 10 pointers to `char` while here `name` is a buffer holding 10 `char`s. You don't need any `malloc` in your code.

Your structure looks like this in memory (assuming 4-bytes `int`s):

[image]

Your `student` array from `main` looks like:

[image]

As you see, fields are laid out one after another. Thus, to read the name of the first student you have to write into `student[0].name` (using `strncpy` to ensure that there's no overflow). To change the third letter of the name of the second student you'll use `student[1].name[2]`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood it a bit. I'm not referring to my **name** character array at all. And do you know the solution to my problem? (The array variable inside an array of structure.

Comment: Perfect visualization @MihaiMaruseac. Brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely use it like this:

```
strcpy(student[1].name, "Yu Hao");
student[1].grades[1] = 95;

printf("student 1 name: %s\n", student[1].name);
printf("student1 grades1:%d\n", student[1].grades[1]);
```

The example you linked uses `malloc` because the `struct` has some pointers, and pointers have to point to somewhere valid before using. That's not the case in your example.

Note that using `strcpy` can lead to disaster when you copy a string longer than 10, if that's to consider, use `strncpy` instead.

Comment: Understood it perfectly.

Comment: Oh by the way, I remembered when you used **strcpy** that we cannot allocate a string to a character array directly like **str = "Yu Hao";** Is the alternative solution like this? : ***str = "Yu Hao";**

Comment: No, there isn't. Also, using `strcpy` is prone to disaster. Think about `strcpy(student[0].name, "A very large string which cleary doesn't fit into the name[10] array")`

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac That's not what is asked here, in case that is, just use `strncpy` instead.

Comment: It was only a suggestion that it is a bad practice to use unchecked string operations.

Comment: @ash9209 No, you can't assign a string literal directly like that. You can initialize like `char name[] = "Yu Hao";` but your `char` array is in a `struct`.

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac It is a good practice, I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question related to the referred post.

First, hope you have basic knowledge about pointers in C.
A pointer is indeed a memory address for short.
For details I recomend you [this](http://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=pointer%20c%20pdf&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/readings/pointers.pdf&ei=O5kHUv7PMIehigegl4GgBA&usg=AFQjCNF7JdqpHJYa1tE6pmvU31Kw8XOWOA&bvm=bv.50500085,d.aGc) booklet (a very excellent introduction about arrays and poiners).
In that piece of codes, the `inputs` is defined as `char* inputs[10];`.
It's an array of pointers.
So each elment in that array should be an address.
The argument `25` in the `malloc` invokation is not necessary (you can also specify `40` or `50` to meet your requirement).
The only thing you should guarantee is that each element in the array is an address (that's what `malloc` returns).
The `10` specifies array dimension, i.e. you can store `10` addresses in total in `inputs` or say, you can initialize the array by invoking `malloc` ten times like:

```
struct a;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    a.inputs[i] = (char *) malloc(25);
}
```

Back to your own problem.
In your case, the symbol `name` identifies the address to the storage.
No need for you to malloc new storage.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the **malloc(25)** part? You said **you can also specify 40 or 50 to meet your requirement**. We need to store 10 addresses in **inputs**. Fine, I get that. I still don't understand how 25 comes in the picture. Where my thinking is leading me, it is allocating 25 bytes to each address in the **inputs** array. Correct? if not, where am I going wrong?

Comment: @ash9209 OK. A pointer is a memory address as I said. It is an address to the underlying memory storage. While we know, like array, to read a chunk of memory we not only need to know its beginning address, also its size (or we'll run out the memory and access to invalid address, I bet you know that when accessing array we should not acess the elments out of the boundary :p). Here is it. The 20, 40, even 50 is the memory size you want to *use* in byte. The actual size is decided by you yourself. If you want a 50-byte memory chunk, np, `malloc(50)` even a 5000-byte one `malloc(5000)`.

Comment: Alright, this was much better. Got it perfectly. Appreciate you giving me your valuable time. Cheers.