# How to accept character array input into a structure in C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I've got this structure, a simple one that holds student name and marks. When I'm trying to read user input into the name(char array), I get a warning indicating something on the lines of :

```
format %s expects char *, but has char*[20]
```

I know this is because `char arrays` cannot be assigned in C, so `strcpy` has to be used. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292586/char-array-in-a-struct-incompatible-assignment) on SO has a good reasoning. However,how do I fix the warning in my program? Don't think I can use strcpy here.

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct _student
{
    char name[20];
    unsigned int marks;
} student;


void read_list(student list[], int SIZE);
void print_list(student list[], int SIZE);

int main()
{
    const int SIZE=3;
    student list[SIZE];

    //function to enter student info.
    read_list(list, SIZE);
    //function to print student info
    print_list(list, SIZE);
    return 0;
}

void read_list(student list[], int SIZE)
{
    int i;
    char nm[20];
    for (i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        printf("\n Please enter name for student %d\n", i);
        scanf("%s",&list[i].name);

        printf("\n Please enter marks for student %d\n", i);
        scanf("%u", &list[i].marks);
    }

}

void print_list(student list[], int SIZE)
{
    int i;
    printf("\t STUDENT NAME  STUDENT MARKS\t \n");

    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        printf("\t %s \t %u\n", list[i].name, list[i].marks);   
    }
}
```

The program does give a correct output, but the warning remains.

Comment: remove the `&` here `scanf("%s",&list[i].name);`

Comment: The program does give a correct output, because for a statically allocated array `arr`, the values of `arr` and `&arr` are identical.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
    for (i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        printf("\n Please enter name for student %d\n", i);
        scanf("%s",list[i].name);

        printf("\n Please enter marks for student %d\n", i);
        scanf("%u", &list[i].marks);
    }
```

This is because `&` used in `scanf` statement is to get the address.

In your case you use array name i.e. `name` and array name itself is providing the address. Remember array name gives the base address of an array.

Answer (score 0):

change `scanf("%s",&list[i].name);` to `scanf("%s",list[i].name);`. Delete `&`. Because basically array name represents base address. No need to mention address of array for scanning the string.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `&` in the `scanf` that scan in a string using `%s` to eliminate the warning. So change

```
scanf("%s",&list[i].name);
```

to

```
scanf("%s",list[i].name);
```

This is because the name of the `char` array decays to a pointer to its first element

Answer (score 0):

line 33:

scanf("%s",&list[i].name);//wrong

scanf("%s",list[i].name);//right

The name of an array is synonym for the location of the initial element , thus in your code, variable 'name' is the address of name[0]. You don't need to use & on 'name' to get the address of the array.Just use 'name' itself.