# String as parameter in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I have a struct containing the command `char var_name[200];` and a typedef after it (`typedef struct list_var* data`) and I have a function that gets the parameter `char* var`. In this function I try the following:

```
data new_var = (data) malloc(sizeof(struct list_var));
new_var->var_name = var
```

But in this line I get an error, saying "incompatible types when assigning to type char[200] from type char*.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this post: [Char array in a struct - incompatible assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292586/char-array-in-a-struct-incompatible-assignment)

Arrays are not assignable in C. You need to use `strcpy`.

```
strcpy(new_var->var_name, var);
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't thought about that, always thought that's it's a problem of the pointer as parameter

Answer (score 1):

use `strcpy` to copy strings:

```
strcpy(new_var->var_name, var);
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't thought about that, always thought that's it's a problem of the pointer as parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
data new_var = (data) malloc(sizeof(struct list_var));
```

You now have allocated memory for a `struct data`, which includes memory for 200 characters, the array `new_var->var_name`.

```
new_var->var_name = var;
```

Now you want to assign a `char *` -- i.e. a pointer -- to an array of 200 characters.

Yes, yes, I know, we call both character arrays and character pointers "strings" at times, but that is just a mental shortcut, and it makes us think the wrong thing pretty often.

You wouldn't expect this here to work either:

```
int array[200];
int x = 42;
array = &x;
```

Why should it work for `char[]` / `char*`?

What you want is [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) / [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy).